# How can I stop snaps from listing in df?

Tags: snap

Ubuntu is using snaps, shown below

> Core applications packaged as snaps

Shown [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/developers)

[image]

---

So, my question is, that since snaps are shown using the `df` command, and they apparently flood `df`.

It's just flooding df, and makes it harder to use.  Is there a way to stop it?  I'm assuming since snap is planning on being used more frequently it will either no show in df, or df will become a much longer command with more pipes.

Comment: You can perhaps do `df | grep -v "/snap"` or similar, but aside from that, no,. Snaps are mounted and so will show up in things which show what is mounted.

Comment: Perhaps you could open a bug report at https://launchpad.net/+ubuntu/source/coreutils about installed snaps being unhelpful in the output.

Comment: You can prevent `df` from listing snaps with the following: `df $(cut -d' ' -f3 /proc/mounts | sort -u | grep -v 'squashfs' | sed 's/^/-t /')`

Comment: I setup an alias:  `alias df='df | grep -v "/snap"' `

Comment: Instead of piping `df` results to grep & removing snaps, the cleaner solution is IMHO to use grep's `grep -v` option to exclude file systems. Snaps use squashfs. Thus you can define an alias like `alias df='df -l -BM -Tx"squashfs"'` to get the non-snap-list as a default.
See [https://docs.snapcraft.io/the-snap-format/698] for a definition.

Comment: @marcus It's a possible solution. Make that an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: 'df -h | egrep -vi snap' is what i use

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use df's `df -x` option to exclude certain file systems from the results. Since snaps use the squashfs filesystem, you can define an alias like

```
alias df='df -x"squashfs"'
```

to get the non-snap-list as a default.

BTW, see [this link](https://docs.snapcraft.io/the-snap-format/698) for a definition of the snap format.

Comment: I'm generally against using alias', but I may make an exception here.  Thanks!

Comment: I still prefer the `grep` solution as this would remove all squashfs filesystems, which is not limited to snaps.

Comment: the difference is that the `grep` solution prevents other arguments to `df` from working.

Comment: @tedder42 `function df() { command df "$@" | grep -v "/snap"; }`

Comment: how is this better than the proper use of df as listed in the answer, @mxmlnkn?

Comment: @tedder42 I prefer it because there might be other valid usecases for squashfs mounts, which I'd want to see. I only want to filter snap. But I only commented this as a response as to how command line arguments would still work by using a function and forwarding the arguments with `$@` instead of an alias.

Comment: The previous function also removes lines which just *happen* to contain `/snap`. My function improves this as well as hide some other 'filesystems' I'm not interested in: `function df() { command df $@ | grep -vE "(% /snap/)|(^tmpfs )|(^udev )"; }`

Comment: @MarkJeronimus I'm no regex expert, but those parenthesis to mark atoms around each of the terms seem superfluous. Can you explain why they are necessary if they are? Thanks. Both `"(% /snap/|^tmpfs |^udev )"` and just `"% /snap/|^tmpfs |^udev "` should work fine I think.

Comment: I'm no regex expert either and in the past I've struggled a lot with the 'alternatives' syntax not working. I think I copy/pasted this from somewhere and was happy it worked at all. On to regex101.com which I just tried, you should use Python syntax to prevent `/` from being interpreted as regex delimiters.

Comment: I also use `alias m='mount | g -v -e cgroup -e fs'` to remove all the crap added to mount.

Comment: `bash: g: command not found`

Answer (score 7):

All the snap filesystems start as `/snap/` so one can use the following command:

```
df | grep -v /snap
```

The `-v` inverses the grep search (list things that *don't* match).

The advantage of this is that it will still show squashfs filesystems if you want them.

You can still use an alias if you wish:

```
alias df='df | grep -v /snap'
```

#### Works With Other Tools (Pydf)

Also, because this is using a pipe to grep, rather than an option of `df`, you can use it for other tools such as `pydf`.

E.g.

```
pydf | grep -v /snap
```

Comment: Using an alias means that you lose access to flags (df -h), so I tweaked this solution to use a function instead: `df() { command df "$*" | command grep -v /snap; }` and added it to my `~/.bashrc`.  This way I can still use `df -h` (or other flags) while still removing the annoyingly large list of snap mountpoints.

Answer (score 5):

I find this one quite handy;

```
df -Thx squashfs
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of way to do this is astronomical ;)

`df | sed /snap/d`